# Replacing a tube on the engine

Tags: ford, focus

I'm trying to replace a tube in my Ford Focus 2000. I tried to look up the schematics for the engine to see what the part is called but I'm pretty newbie so I don't know what I'm doing.

Luckly the tube is quite obvious and I have found an image that shows exactly where it's located.

[image]

It's the tube that sticks out from the engine (if the picture doesn't make it obvious enough). I just need to know what I'm looking for when I'm going to go buy one.

Comment: I have a 2001 Focus with this style engine in it (the power steering pump placement is different). It is not the engine that was in the car originally which has complicated the process of getting parts. Do you remember what car the engine came out of? It would really help me to know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be the **PCV Valve / Crankcase Ventilation Hose**. You can find it on Rockauto.com for about $12 + shipping. Motorcraft part number KCV118 (as long as your car has the SOHC engine).