# Ford focus choking in neutral

Tags: ford, focus

I have recently (well quite recently about 7 months) replaced the SOHC in my 2000 Ford Focus. The cylinder was busted which made the car choke and eventually die when stopped at the red lights. It initially caused no trouble when driving but eventually car would start loosing power and started turning off in higher gears.

Once I replaced the overhead cam everything seemed to run smoothly for a while but now the car is choking when parked in neutral again. I wonder what are possible causes for this problem? Did the previous mechanic botch the job? Should I take my car to the mechanic right away to prevent further damage or it doesn't really matter if I wait until the car fails completely?

Comment: Could this valve be a reason for this? http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/replacing-a-tube-on-the-engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have replaced the PCV pipe and the choking stopped. It still makes strange noises on neutral but i guess i fixed the biggest problem.