# whats going on with my cruise control

Tags: ford, focus, cruise-control

Couple of months ago my cruise control in my ford focus 2000 stopped working. I have used it extensively in the past.

Now When i press the on and set button the green cruise light turns on but it does not hold the speed which i set.

Is there anything i can try to do before i turn the car over to the mechanic to fix it?

Do you guys have any idea how much a repair like that could cost?

Answer (score 1):

Did it stop working about the time you had the work done to your car (about 7 months ago I think you said)? Could be your mechanic didn't hook it back up, either physically or electronically. If so, take it back to *that* mechanic and have them take a look.

You can check the photo you posted in [your other thread](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/replacing-a-tube-on-the-engine), there are two cables which are to the right of the oil filler cap and to the left of your red circle. One of those cables goes to your accelerator pedal, the other goes to cruise control. Check to ensure both of those are attached to your throttle body (on the engine side). Also, follow those two cables back the other way. One will go to the firewall and into the cabin. This is attached to your accelerator pedal. The other one should be attached to a diaphragm or electric servo. If a diaphragm, ensure this is attached to a vacuum source. If a servo, it should have power/control wires plugged into it. If you find a socket on it without a wire plugged into it, you've probably found your issue.

Cost on repair is going to depend on what is wrong and where you take it. No way to tell you over the internet.